# Как в numpy найти индек элемента в массиве?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, index

Как при помощи numpy найти индекс элемента массива по значению?
Например есть массив **'array'** с размерами (5,3,3), из всего этого массива был выделен минимум и помещён в массив **'minArray'** с размерами (3,3). необходимо найти и поместить в массив **'indexOfMin'**, индексы элементов **'minArray'** из **'array'**.
Что-то типа:

```
    for i in range(len(array)):
        indexOfMin = array[i].index(minArray)
```

Если выразится по другому нужно узнать на каком слое массива **'array'** находиться значение из массива **'minArray'**.
Если делать это при помощи нескольких 'for' ,то это очень долго.
Заранее спасибо.

[image: Абстрактноепредставление]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randint(1, 50, size=(5,3,3))
min_idx=np.argmin(a, axis=0)
```

Результат:

```
a
Out[1]: 
array([[[28, 20, 12],
        [34, 23,  6],
        [36, 20, 28]],

       [[29, 35, 43],
        [38, 24, 35],
        [39, 19,  4]],

       [[27, 12, 49],
        [22, 32, 47],
        [22, 44, 36]],

       [[49, 38, 40],
        [47, 48, 14],
        [45, 20, 16]],

       [[40,  4, 43],
        [39, 22, 19],
        [33, 29,  5]]])

min_idx
Out[2]: 
array([[2, 4, 0],
       [2, 4, 0],
       [2, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```